# Delphi OOP timer message

Tags: delphi, oop, timer

Finding the timer thread is the issue. I have a parent object with a timer message copied out of TCustomGrid.

```
  private  
    procedure WMTimer(var Msg: TWMTimer); message WM_TIMER; .....................................
```

Its parent is TWinControl. It calls `TimerEvent(ID: Integer); virtual;` in the protected part of my object. I override this in my descendant object and the procedure first contains `Inherited;` in it. I use a `SetTimer(Handle, 1, 60, nil);` in my create and in the procedure TimerEvent last uses `KillTimer(Handle, 1);` at the bottom. WMTimer fitted with a breakpoint, but will not stop the timer thread anywhere in my code. Also `TimerEvent(ID: Integer);` has a break point with same result everywhere. I have no problems with the object's handle as I'm using it for other things with no problems. Am I missing something like some hit call.

Comment: Show the code, ask a question.

Comment: Lex, Please edit your answer and include complete code blocks instead of tiny fragments from here and there. The curly braces on top of the editor is a button to get code formatting of selected text. It does not mean that you should type those braces.

Answer (score 1):

> Finding the timer thread is the issue.

Timers do not create threads. The timer messages and callbacks are executed on the thread that called `SetTimer`.

Whatever your problem is, it's not related to the existence of a timer thread. If you want further help with the problem I suggest you post a new question with an MCVE.

---

At a wild guess, you could very well be subject to VCL window re-creation. The window handle that you pass when you create the timer has destroyed and re-created during the lifetime of the VCL control. This is very normal behaviour.

You should not use a VCL control's window handle in this way since the window is subject to re-creation. Instead use a bespoke window handle created with a call to `AllocateHWnd`. The point about windows created with `AllocateHWnd` is that you are in control of their lifetime.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You asked how to find the timer thread, which is what I answered.

Comment: Call it what you want, I need the timer to execute its code from message WM_TIMER. Just stop complicating things away from the issue.

Comment: What we do here is answer the questions that are asked. You asked about a timer thread. If you wish to present an MCVE and ask about your actual problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: Can the handle be missing in create that I cannot set the timer. can I do this another way.

Comment: Yes, it's very plausible that's the actual problem. You need to be using AllocateHWnd as I explain more in the updated answer.

Comment: TTimer's Create uses FWindowHandle := Classes.AllocateHWnd(WndProc); And that requires the method WndProc too. It is a TComponent descendant and not a TWinControl descendant that would call the handle a 2nd time I guess. will that be a conflict in some way. Can I get the parent form obtain a AfterConstruction to get a handle. Also Classes.DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle); i would place in my Distroy.

Comment: VCL window recreation can happen at any time in the control's life. Use `AllocateHWnd` as I said.

Comment: SO it's much easier to place TTimer in my object and dispose of it even though I have a message WM_TIMER method.

Comment: I was fully mislead, you cannot place a timer into a object safely until the object gets its own handle. The information that is obtained from comments above interferes with objects handle. There are some ways to consider overcoming the first CreateWin statement is the first place to obtain a handle safely in a VCL.